# What kind of answer is this textbook question looking for in access control model?

Tags: access-control, file-system

I'm going over a practice question and I have trouble understanding what it's asking.

> Draw an access control matrix for the following Linux file system.
>   Group A1 contains S1 and S3, group A2 contains S3. Only show users as
>   subjects.
>
> [image: file system]

So is the answer to the question supposed to look like

[image: answer?]

What is the answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

So to summarize:

- Group 1 contains S1 and S3
- Group 2 contains S3

---

Then it is pretty simple, if you know that in Linux, the 9-character permission scheme can be divided as [follows](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions):

- First three characters are the owner's permissions
- Next three characters are the group's permissions
- Last three characters are the permissions of all of the other users

Then, following the assumption I made, you know the following:

```
Permissions    a     b    c
S1             rwx   -    rwx (S1 is member of group 1: group 1 has rwx permission)
S2             rwx   rwx  - (due to explicit owner deny on the last row of the table)
S3             rwx   -    rwx (due to group inherited allow permission of group 1)
```

Comment: From the diagram (`ls -la`) output is it possible to infer what group S2 belongs to?

Comment: @Celeritas, sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by this? What is the (ls - la) output?

Comment: Basically I'm asking, can you explain why you think the question is not consistent?

Comment: I'm asking, from the first diagram, is it possible to infer which users are in which group (e.g. somehow using process of elimination)?

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my answer (above the horizontal line): ////. You say that: Group 1 contains S1 and S3; Group 2 contains S3. /// From the image, it shows that:Group 1 contains S1 and S2;Group 2 contains S1////From the solution, it shows that: S3 is in group 2

Comment: but how do you know from the image Group 2 contains S1?

Comment: You are correct, I assumed that the table rows of the first image could be used to define which user belongs to which group. However, I updated my answer to only use your problem description.